# Aajx Rails Routes 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, routes, internal-server-error

I have created custom rails actions in my campaigns controller to be called from ajax upon button click. However, upon clicking the button 500 server errors appear.

How can the 500 Server Errors be alleviated?

The Error Log:
[image]

Routes:

```
  match "/create_campaign_location_relationship/:location_id/:campaign_id", to: "campaigns#create_campaign_location_relationship", via: 'post'

  match "/delete_campaign_location_relationship/:location_id/:campaign_id", to: "campaigns#delete_campaign_location_relationship", via: 'delete'
```

campaigns.js.coffee:
    for aNewLocation in newLocations

```
  location_id = aNewLocation
  $.ajax({
    url: "/create_campaign_location_relationship/" + location_id + "/" + campaign_id,  
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json"
  })

for aRemovedLocation in removedLocations

  if aRemovedLocation != 0
    location_id = aRemovedLocation

    # Removing no longer selected locations
    $.ajax({
      url: "/delete_campaign_location_relationship/" + location_id + "/" + campaign_id,  
      type: "delete",
      dataType: "json"
    })

return
```

Campaigns Controller:

```
def create_campaign_location_relationship
        @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
        @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:campaign_id])

        @insert = CampaignLocation.new(campaign_id: @campaign.id,
                                       location_id: @location.id)
        @insert.save

    end

    def delete_campaign_location_relationship
        @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
        @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:campaign_id])

        CampaignLocation.where(campaign_id: @campaign.id, location_id: @location.id).destroy_all
    end
```

result of rake routes:

```
POST   /create_campaign_location_relationship/:location_id/:campaign_id(.:format)                         campaigns#create_campaign_location_relationship

DELETE /delete_campaign_location_relationship/:location_id/:campaign_id(.:format)                         campaigns#delete_campaign_location_relationship

           campaigns POST   /campaigns(.:format)
                                               campaigns#create
       edit_campaign GET    /campaigns/:id/edit(.:format)
                                               campaigns#edit
            campaign GET    /campaigns/:id(.:format)
                                               campaigns#show
                     PATCH  /campaigns/:id(.:format)
                                               campaigns#update
                     PUT    /campaigns/:id(.:format)
                                               campaigns#update
                     DELETE /campaigns/:id(.:format)
                                               campaigns#destroy
         restaurants POST   /restaurants(.:format)
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: To the right of the `delete_campaign_location_relation` line it seems to be saying `sessions#destroy` rather than `campaigns#delete_campaign_location_relationship`. Is that just a formatting thing? You should see the proper controller#action pair there as defined in `routes.rb`

Comment: @sixty4bit My apologies, it was a formatting issue, now corrected

Comment: Hmm this looks correct to me. I even threw a few similar lines in a new Rails app's `routes.rb` to try accessing it with cURL and see if the route worked and it was fine. What happens if you temporarily add `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` to your controller, start your server, and then in another terminal window run `curl -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/delete_campaign_location_relationship/1/1` ?

Comment: @sixty4bit You are correct there is nothing wrong. It ended up that Sunspot Solr was trying to index and having issues in Heroku when there was no Solr (WebSolr in heroku) addon configured, so it kept crashing. as it was trying to insert new entries into the database. I simply removed the Solr gem and commented out the `Searchable` unused code. Thank you for the support, it all works now

Comment: As a side note, your route naming conventions are breaking those expected in REST. Ideally you should have something like: `match '/campaign/:campaign_id/location/:location_id', to: 'campaign_locations#create', via: "post"` and `match '/campaign/:campaign_id/location/:location_id', to: 'campaign_locations#destroy', via: "delete"`. This keeps to the RESTful way of using the HTTP verbs to determine the type of action being taken on a resource, and the route just describing the resource.

Comment: If the route functions, is there any issue what the action is named?